# laravel way generators doesn't create the controller

Tags: php, laravel

The laravel way generator is not creating the controller, it creates the views, the model and everything but the controller, it shows me this error on the console:

> [ErrorException] 
>   file_put_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\noticias-laravel2\app/Http/Controllers/No
>   ticiasController.php): failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory.

Any ideas about why is this happening?.
Im using laravel 4.2

Comment: Show the command, how you generate the controller

Answer (score 0):

Try composer update first. Then try generate controller again. Which version laravel & generator do you use?